# SQL server - Using Avg() function in where clause

Tags: sql-server, average

I am working on a feedback job, I want to fetch the list of drivers in last 30 days who got 5 star ratings from their customers,they should have an avg of 25% 5 star ratings out of their total trips in last 30 days and minimum 10 5 star ratings

Using the below query I can get drivers who got more than 10 5 star ratings in last 30 days, but i need to check that they should have avg 25% 5 star ratings out of their total trips.

```
Select DriverId, Count(DriverId) as TotalStars from tblTripfeedback
where Rating = 5 and TripDate >= GetDate() - 30 
group by DriverId
Having Count(DriverId) > 10
```

How can I include avg condition in the above query

when i try to get their average of 5 star ratings in my select query using below query i am getting the DriverId in the average column.
    Select DriverId, Count(DriverId) as TotalStars, avg(DriverId) as Average from tblTripfeedback
    where Rating = 5 and TripDate >= GetDate() - 30 
    group by DriverId
    Having Count(DriverId) > 10

Ex - Driver with Id 123 has completed 20 trips in last 30 days and he received 15 5 star ratings from his customers which means 50 %  5 star ratings, and he also met the other condition of minimum 10 trips.. This means he is eligible for rewards as he got more than 25% 5 star ratings and also minimum of 10 trips

Comment: [Edit] the question and add a [example], i.e. the schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data as tabular text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the condition `Rating = 5` from the `WHERE` clause, so that the query returns all the rows of the last month and use it to get the results with conditional aggregation:

```
select DriverId, 
  count(case when Rating = 5 then DriverId end) as TotalStars,
  100.0 * avg(case when Rating = 5 then 1.0 else 0 end) as Average5Stars
from tblTripfeedback
where TripDate >= GetDate() - 30 
group by DriverId
having 
  count(case when Rating = 5 then DriverId end) > 10 
  and  
  100.0 * avg(case when Rating = 5 then 1.0 else 0 end) > 25
```

Comment: This is working great but only issue is when the driver has all 5 star ratings then the average is shown as 100.0 , if there is atleast 1 non 5 star rating than the avg is diaplayed as 0.0... The result in average column is either 100.0 or 0.0

Comment: The having clause is having an issue, its throwing an error invalid column name 'TotalStars' and 'Average5Stars'

Comment: Yes SQL Server does not allow derived columns in the having clause. See my edited answer.